# Redirection error occurs only on "ls" command. Other commands are redirected well. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, redirect

I'm doing a small school project making my own bash shell. 
It must include simple redirection function.

I almost made it... following commands work well 'pwd > sample', 'cat sample > sample1', 'echo sentence > sample2'

However, 'ls > sample' command is malfunctioning! 
Whenever I do this, it makes a new file but it's empty. If a 'sample' file already exist and not empty, 'ls > sample' command makes the file empty.

Just a single 'ls' command itself works very well, showing all files and dir names even though they are not alphabetically sorted.

I can't find something wrong with my code.. please somebody help me.

Below is redirection part

```
int bak, new;
int redirLoca;  // indicates ">" location in argv[].

else if (boolRedirect == 1) {  
    redirLoca = checkRedirLoca(argc, argv); 
    fflush(stdout);
    bak = dup(1);       
    new = open(argv[redirLoca + 1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777); 
    dup2(new, 1);
    close(new);
    executeCmd(argc, argv, boolCorrect, cmdNum, boolRedirect);  // 'ls' command executed here.
    fflush(stdout);
    dup2(bak, 1);
    close(bak);
    }
```

And here is implementation of 'ls' command.

```
int list_ls(int argc, char **argv)
{

DIR *dirP;
struct dirent *direntP;

if (argc == 1) {        
    dirP = opendir(".");

    while ((direntP = readdir(dirP)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", direntP -> d_name);
    }

    closedir(dirP);
} else if (argc == 2) { 
    dirP = opendir(argv[1]);

    while ((direntP = readdir(dirP)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", direntP -> d_name);
    }

    closedir(dirP);
}

return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: try using `freopen(file_name, "w", stdout)`

Comment: `if (argc == 1) { `, `} else if (argc == 2) { ` : but argc == 3 or  argc ==4 when boolRedirect == 1

Comment: You should check the return values on all the system calls and use perror() to print the result.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Jesus Christ!!! You exactly pointed out my problem~ Thank you so much!!

Comment: Note that redirection information should not be passed to the executed commands; it is read and used by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

man dup2 says:

"The dup2() system call performs the same task as dup(), but instead of using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor, it uses the descriptor number specified in newfd.  If the descriptor newfd was previously open, it  is  silently  closed  before  being reused."

You are placing your opened parameter file inplace of stdout and closing the stdout. That makes stdout output always zero length creating zero length redirected files.

Addition: You could try to debug the issue with strace to see what system level operations your application is doing. Then you can check man pages for each call to see what it does with given parameters.